# Using callback function result to implemlent res.render in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-oracledb

I am using oracledb for node to fetch data from the database. After fetching the data, I am trying to send the data to client side using **render()** in express JS. The code is like this -

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  user          : "user",
  password      : "password",
  connectString : "*connstring*"  ,
  deliveredQuery: " SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT order_num) AS Cnt from orders where department = 'HR'
};
```

**query2.js**

```
module.exports = function(callback) {//pass callback function and return with this
  var oracledb = require('oracledb');
  var dbConfig = require('./config.js');

  this.queryDB = function(query,callback) {
    oracledb.getConnection({
      user: dbConfig.user,
      password: dbConfig.password,
      connectString: dbConfig.connectString,
      deliveredQuery: dbConfig.deliveredQuery    
    }, function(err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return callback(err);
      }
      connection.execute(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          doRelease(connection);
          return;
        }
        //console.log(result.metaData);
        //console.log(JSON.parse(result.rows[0][0]));
        doRelease(connection);
        return callback(null, JSON.parse(result.rows[0][0]))
      });
    });

    function doRelease(connection) {
      connection.release(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return callback(err);
        }
      });
    }
  };
};
```

**serv_ontime.js**

```
var dbConfig = require('./config.js');
var res = require('./query2.js')();
var onTime_query = dbConfig.onTime_query;

module.exports = function (callback) {
    queryDB(onTime_query, callback)
};
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var serv_ontime = require('./serv_ontime.js');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/src/views');   
var bookRouter= express.Router();
app.set('view engine','ejs');

    bookRouter.route('/')
          .get(function(req,res){
              serv_ontime(function(error, result){
                  res.render('index', 
                                    {title: 'Hello',
                                     rec: result
                                    });
              });
          });
```

Now when I am doing **node app.js** in cmd it shows the following error -

[image: Error]

Can anyone help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Where is onTime_query in dbconfig.js:

```
var onTime_query = dbConfig.onTime_query;
```

Are you sure it is written.

Comment: Yes the query was there actually. I got it resolved now. I think it was an issue with the node oracledb only. I reinstalled it and my code worked.